# GTK+, GtkBuilder

Tags: c, gtk+

Не совсем понимаю алгоритм работы с **GtkBuilder**.

Я вижу это так:

1) Создаем объект **GtkBuilder**;

2) Загружаем файл с описанием интерфейса, чтобы билдер смог построить все требуемые нам виджеты с нужными свойствами и связями;

3) Получаем из билдера указатели на объекты, с которыми собираемся что-то делать, как то - активные кнопки, метки, которые мы хотели бы менять, и пр.;

Поскольку у нас теперь имеются указатели на виджеты, с которыми мы хотим связать какие-то действия, то нужен ли нам далее объект **GtkBuilder**?

Если его удалить, он удалится вместе с неполученными виджетами, со всеми виджетами или как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Поскольку у нас теперь имеются указатели на виджеты, с которыми мы хотим связать какие-то действия, то нужен ли нам далее объект GtkBuilder?

Нет, его можно удалить, как обычно с помощью `g_object_unref ()`.

> Если его удалить, он удалится вместе с неполученными виджетами, со всеми виджетами или как?

Если верить [документации](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html#GtkBuilder.description), то он удаляется вместе со всеми объектами и виджетами, которые **НЕ** являются частью окон верхнего уровня (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL) и явно небыли востребованы пользователем/gtk c помощью g_object_ref () или g_object_ref_sink ().

Фактически же `GtkBuilder` удерживает ссылки на все объекты, которые он создал. А при уничтожении отпускает их, что приводит к уничтожению объектов, если их ни кто другой их не затребовал (а счётчик ссылок соответственно опускается до нуля). Для окон верхнего уровня ссылку удерживают сами внутренности gtk. Для виджетов содержащихся внутри них — их родители. Для всех остальных — это задача пользователя.

#### Небольшой пример

Замечание, в *ui*-файле описан только содержимое, без собственно окна

**gtkbuilder-ex1.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<interface>
  <object class="GtkVBox" id="mainVBox">
    <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkLabel" id="hwLbl">
        <property name="label" translatable="yes"></property>
      </object>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkButton" id="hwBtn">
        <property name="label" translatable="yes">Click me!</property>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

**gtkbuilder-ex1.c**

```
// build with: 
// gcc -g -O0 -Wall gtkbuilder-ex1.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -o gtkbuilder-ex1

#include <assert.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkLabel   *hwLbl;

void on_mainWnd_destroy (GtkWidget *wgt, gpointer user_data) {
    gtk_main_quit();
}

void on_hwBtn_click (GtkWidget *wgt, gpointer user_data) {
    gtk_label_set_text (hwLbl, "Hello world!");
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    GtkBuilder *builder = gtk_builder_new ();
    guint rc = gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "gtkbuilder-ex1.ui", 0);
    assert (rc != 0);

    GtkWidget  *mainWnd = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_object_connect (mainWnd, "signal::destroy", on_mainWnd_destroy, NULL, NULL);

    GtkWidget *mainVBox  = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "mainVBox"));
    hwLbl = GTK_LABEL (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "hwLbl"));

    g_object_connect (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "hwBtn"),
                      "signal::clicked", on_hwBtn_click, NULL,
                      NULL);

    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (mainWnd), mainVBox);
    g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (builder)); // уничтожение виджета 

    gtk_widget_show_all (mainWnd);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

Если поменять местами удаление `builder`'а и добавление `mainVBox`'а к окну, то это сломает программу т.к. к моменту добавления виджет уже будет удалён.

```
    g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (builder)); // уничтожение виджета 
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (mainWnd), mainVBox);
```

Если же явно взять на него ссылку, то всё будет работать:

```
    g_object_ref (G_OBJECT (mainVBox));
    g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (builder)); // уничтожение виджета 
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (mainWnd), mainVBox);
    g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (mainVBox));
```

Comment: Как все запутанно, спасибо, что объяснили.

Comment: если копать вглубь, то glib/gtk всё запутанное... так получается когда пытаешься сделать объектно-ориентированную модель без поддержки со стороны яззыка... но если не копать вглубь, а просто «рисовать окошечки», то всё просто: создал builder→загрузил→закрыл builder...

Comment: Ага, то есть, если в моем файле glade описано окно верхнего уровня с кучей виджетов внутри, то мне достаточно сказать GTK, что окно затребовано, чтобы при удалении объекта GtkBuilder удалился лишь сам билдер, но при этом загруженные виджеты остались в памяти?

Comment: Да, только вот окно верхнего уровня не удалится даже если не было затребовано. По сути `gtk_builder_get_object ()` ни как не влияет на то, будет ли что-либо удалено.

Comment: Все очень непросто